# Location manager not updating heading

Tags: iphone, ios, cllocationmanager, compass-geolocation, heading

Has anyone experienced this problem? When we start heading updates on a Location Manager instance, we never receive a single heading update from it. Further, the heading field of the location manager is always nil.

What's even crazier is this: every single app on **my test device that requires heading updates DOES NOT WORK**. By this I mean Apple's own compass app is stuck on 0 degrees. It does not detect any interference and no amount of figure-8 waving fixes it. It is quite obvious even Apple's compass app is not receiving heading updates either.

I have no idea how the device enters this state, but I am worried that perhaps my code has done this.

The only way I am able to solve this problem is by restarting the device. However, one of my customers said that even rebooting the phone did not solve the problem and that it had to be restored.

Thanks

Comment: I'm interested if anyone has any ideas on this also, I have run into the same problem.

Comment: did you ever find it out what caused the problem?